# Add $5000 to existing retirement account

Tags: united-states, 401k

I have an employer sponsored account(401k by Fidelity) which was opened in my first company. Now I am in another company. To reduce my tax liability, can I add $5000 to the account so the amount is tax deductible?

Comment: are you still with that company?

Comment: No,I changed my job two years ago.

Comment: _You_ cannot contribute to a 401k plan of an ex-employer; in fact, technically, an employer _reduces_ your salary (at your request) and sends the amount of the reduction to your (non-Roth) 401k account. So, no salary, no contribution.  Now, if you had _deferred compensation_ due from your previous employer that is being paid to you this year, it might be possible to arrange to have the ex-employer send some part of it to the 401k account still there in the ex-employer's 401k plan....

Comment: @Dilip answering as comment... hrrrm :/ grumble grumble ;)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Sorry, I didn't have time to carefully write up a complete answer (which would have included the points raised in the comments on Jeremy's accepted answer.)

Comment: Does the current employer not offer a 401(k)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot contribute directly to that 401k account if you no longer work at the sponsoring company - you have to be on their payroll.

You can, however, roll the 401k over into an IRA, and contribute to the IRA. Note that in both cases, you are only allowed to contribute from earned income (which includes all the taxable income and wages you get from working or from running your own business). As long as you are employed (and have made more than $5k this year) you should have no problem.

I am not certain whether contributing your $5k to a roth IRA would help you achieve your tax goals, someone else here certainly can advise.

Comment: I have some money in my checking account, the rate is low. I want the purpose of tax deductible. What is the best way?

Comment: @Love - how to use existing liquid assets to create a tax deduction is a good new question (although a bit open ended), as such you might consider posting it as a new question on this site.

Comment: "You can't throw $5000 from your savings account into a traditional IRA." This is not very correct. Transferring money from a bank account *is* usually how you contribute to an IRA; you just also need to have at least $5000 in income that year. Since the OP said he is working in another company, I assume that would be true.

Comment: @Love Though not applicable in this instance since you say you are currently employed, be aware that you cannot contribute to an IRA unless you have _earned income_, whether it is W-2 wages or self-employment income. Sending money sitting in your checking account to the IRA custodian is fine, that is, the money doesn't _have_ to come from your paycheck.  Also, be aware that if your Adjusted Gross Income is large enough, you cannot make a _tax-deductible_ contribution to an IRA, though non-deductible contributions are allowed.

Comment: @user102008, my income is great than $5000. I just want to transfer some money to an existing 401k account, since the deposit rate is too low and I will be taxed too much..

Comment: @Love ...and you have been told twice that you _cannot_ transfer money into an existing 401k account with a previous employer. In fact, _you_ cannot deposit money into a 401k account, only your employer can, on your behalf, as a deduction from salary; and of course, the employer can also deposit employer-match money into your 401k account.

Comment: So can I open a new IRA accounT by myself?

Comment: >So can I open a new IRA account by myself?  Yes, in fact _only you_ can open an IRA account in your name. The I in IRA stands for _Individual_, which means, among other things, that there is no such thing as a  joint IRA account with your spouse or with your employer, etc.

Comment: @user102008 thanks for the clarification, I will edit as such.